# How can I access my SQLite3 database on a live application?

Tags: node.js, sqlite, node-sqlite3

So basically I have a SQLite3 Database that I am using for a Discord Bot. Is it possible for me to access my database file to check what's inside while the application is hosted and live?

I've considered that it is probably possible to do this from the command line within my terminal that I use to access the virtual host, but I do not know where to begin/what to input.

Ideally I would want to be able to view the file inside the `DB Browser for SQLite` program, for visual purposes, but for starters I want to know if its possible to see the live-updated database remotely, as my application is hosted on a virtual host/machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can install phpliteadmin (https://www.phpliteadmin.org/) on your server to view your database.
Otherwise your can download your database file and view it in a client (Example of online client: https://extendsclass.com/sqlite-browser.html)